# How can I change this in my navigation bar and how can i change the code soo that it can fit any screen?

Tags: html, css, screen, navigationbar

I have 2 big questions and I will be thankfull if you could please answer Thank you ( I am noew into programming):  1) I don`t know how to change my text so it can fit every screen(iphone ipad laptop...)  2) And how can I move the elements English, French ... to the right (my languages)  so that it stays in the same horizontal line. 
thanks

```css
.code {
    overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 111%;
}



#navigation-container img {
  float: left;
  height: 111%;
}

#navigation-container ul {
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#navigation-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

#navigation-container li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#menu {
  float: center;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #0099cc;
}
 hr {
 color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css" type="text/css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="navigation-bar">


    <div id="navigation-container">

      <img src="Bildschirmfoto%202017-10-08%20um%2012.01.55.png">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Who are we ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Best</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
     
      </ul>
        
    
        
     <hr >
    </div>
   </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just google these things: viewport tag, media queries, responsive design tutorial and you should be good.

Comment: media queries and bootstrap Grid View is Very good for Responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work with minimal changes as long as you want the desktop nav layout on mobile.

https://codepen.io/will0220/pen/YrabEm

You'll want to change the nav bar and nav bar wrapper to be 100% width - you can add a max-width if you don't want it to exceed a specific size. From there, add a media query for smaller devices that kicks off at a smaller size (1000px in my example but it can be lower) and switch to viewport units for the font size/padding of the nav elements. This is only if you want the full desktop nav on mobile - it's probably better to look for an alternate mobile menu for usability, but this will at least make it fit as-is.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #navigation-container li a{
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 5px 1vw
  }
}
```